# CSS modules with Webpack

Tags: css, webpack, css-modules

Hi all I'm trying to use CSS modules in my simple webpack project. The problem is that after compiling, webpack doesn't attach style class to my HTML element.

I can see an array with my encoded styles in `console.log(styles)`. But class is not added to my divs.

Can some one help me with this please?

[image]

```
**package.json**

  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
  }


**webpack.config.js**

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    // Path to your entry point. From this file Webpack will begin his work
    entry: './src/js/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/assets'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                    modules: true,
                },
            },
        ]

    }
};


**src/js/app.js**

import styles from "./css.module.css";
let el = document.getElementById('main');
el.innerHTML=  '<div class="'+styles.red+'">RED OR NOT RED! This is the problem!</div>';

**src/js/css.module.css**

.red{ color: red; }

**public/index.html**

<div id="main"></div>
<script src="assets/main.bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is your console output?

Comment: <div class="undefined">RED OR NOT RED! This is the problem!</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`style-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader) to inject your css into dom.

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        modules: true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: hi Arseny, thx, it's work but is mandatory to inject in the dom? imagine that i have a lot of component in my page like buttons, arrows etc... all in dom?

Comment: No it is not mandatory and it is actually better to extract css to separate files when you create production build. To do that you will nee to use [MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/)